# How to get data from JSON data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

I have JSON like this:

```
[{"ID" : "351", "Name" : "Cam123 ", "camIP" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "Username" : "admin", "Password" : "damin", "isSupportPin" : "1" },
 {"ID" : "352", "Name" : "Cam122 ", "camIP" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "Username" : "admin", "Password" : "damin", "isSupportPin" : "0" }
]
```

I want to get `isSupportPin` with result: *1* or *0*.

```
if (x == 1)
{
    mybutton.enabled = TRUE;
}
else
{
    mybutton.enabled = FALSE;   
}
```

How I can do it?

Comment: i think you want to convert JSON data into dictionary .am i right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you have is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s. So using SBJSON library you could do as following

```
SBJsonParser *parser =  [SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray *data = [parser objectFromString:youJson];
for (NSDictionary *d in data)
{
    NSString *value = [d objectForKey:@"Name"];
}
```

The library can be found at http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

Comment: Unless you need to target older versions of iOS, it's best to use the newer Foundation classes for JSON serialization. They're very fast, they're available in Foundation with no accidents, they don't add categories that could make debugging harder, and they follow the exact same pattern as all the other Foundation serialization classes, meaning once you learn the pattern, you can serialize/deserialize property lists, NSCoding compliant classes, JSON data, etc. with relative ease.

Comment: You can call me old fashioned ;) but excellent point though. Our clients usually demand at least iOS 4.3.

Comment: Yeah, one of the first things I did for any of our code that required non-iOS 5 when it came out was to dynamically add this class and fall down to an external JSON library, but at least that way everything still used the new pattern, and anything running iOS 5+ used the new classes directly :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an NSData object with this data in it:

```
// Your JSON is an array, so I'm assuming you already know
// this and know which element you need. For the purpose
// of this example, we'll assume you want the first element
NSData* jsonData = /* assume this is your data from somewhere */
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
if( !array ) {
  // there was an error with the structure of the JSON data...
}
if( [array count] > 0 ) {
  // we got our data in Foundation classes now...
  NSDictionary* elementData = array[0]; // pick the correct element
  // Now, extract the 'isSupportPin' attribute
  NSNumber* isSupportPin = elementData[@"isSupportPin"];
  // Enable the button per this item
  [mybutton setEnabled:[isSupportPin boolValue]];
} else {
  // Valid JSON data, but no elements... do something useful
}
```

The above example code snippet assumes you know which element you want to read (I guess these are user lines or something) and that you know what the JSON attribute names are (e.g., if `isSupportPin` isn't actually defined in the JSON object returned in that array, it will simply return nil, which will always evaluate to `NO` when you send it `-boolValue`).

Finally, the above code is written for ARC and requires Xcode 4.5 or Clang 4.1 and a deployment target of iOS 5.0. If you're not using ARC, building with a legacy version of Xcode, or targeting something earlier than 5.0, you'll have to adjust the code.

Comment: Hey Jason. Your JSON parsing line seems to be missing the NSJSONSerialization class name. Shouldn't `NSArray* array = [JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error]` actually be `NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error]`?

Comment: @MattLong You're right!! Oops :) thanks for the heads up! Please feel free to edit my answers for correctness anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link that my help you.

http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data or Dictionary fron JSONData then use bellow code..

```
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSArray *resultsArray = [responseString JSONValue];
for(NSDictionary *item in resultsArray)
{
    NSDictionary *project = [item objectForKey:@"result"];//use your key name insted of result
    NSLog(@"%@",project);
}
```

and also download JSON Library and tutorial from below link...

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/